# Backbone and user confirmation - jquery defer and promises

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, promise, jquery-deferred

I am working with jQuery defer and promises for the first time, and I am running into a little bit of confusion that I am hoping someone clear up for me, in a view I have a checkbox, that determines the value of a model attribute. I am wanting to throw a confirmation as the user checks this input, and based on either a positive or a negative response go from there.

So far I have this in my models view,

```
App.Views.UserInitialsWithAdmin = Backbone.View.extend({

className : 'avatar-member',

template: _.template( $('#tpl-person-initials-with-admin').html() ),

events: {
    "change input[type=checkbox]" : "changeAdmin"
},

initialize: function() {
    this.model.on('change:is_admin', this.doAdmin, this );
},

changeAdmin: function(e) {
    var element = $(e.currentTarget);
    if(element.is(':checked')) {
        this.model.set('is_admin', true);
    } else {
        this.model.set('is_admin', false);
    }
},

doAdmin: function() {

    var self = this;
    var notify = new Pops.Views.ConfirmationView({
        message : "Are you sure?"
    });
    $.when(notify.render().promise)
        .then(function() {
           console.log("the user wants to change the admin");
        }).fail(function() {
            console.log("the user does not want to change the admin");
        });

}
```

});

So at the moment, I am just wanting to log what the user is wanting to do, here is my confirmation view,

```
'use strict'
```

App.Views.ConfirmationView = Backbone.View.extend({

```
tagName: 'div',
className: 'notification',

template: _.template( $('#tpl-cofirmation').html() ),

initialize: function(options) {
    this.options = options;
    console.log(this);
},

events: {
    "click .js-cancel" : "cancel",
    "click .js-confirm": "confirm"
},

render: function() {
    //var self = this;
    console.log(this);
    this.$el.html(this.template({
        message: this.options.message
    })).css({'z-index':'9999', 'position':'absolute', 'padding':'10px', 'background':'#fff'}).prependTo('.app');

    this.deferred = $.Deferred();

    return this.deferred;
},

cancel: function() {
    this.$el.hide();
    this.deferred.reject();
},

confirm: function() {
    this.$el.hide();
    this.deferred.resolve();
}
```

});

The problem that I am having is regardless of what I click in the confirmation the model view always things that I am giving a positive response and logging "the user wants to change the admin" - I am really new to deferring things so any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not saying you couldn't or shouldn't use promises for this but have you considered using Backbone's built-in events functionality instead? For instance you could trigger events from the ConfirmationView that pass back to the UserInitialsWithAdminView the specific messages that need to be logged to the console.

Comment: How would that work? I figured I could manipulate a model from another view that does not have that model?

Comment: Check out Backbone's trigger and listenTo methods. The basic idea is that your admin view would listen for an event or events that are triggered from the confirmation view. Your admin view could then react accordingly based on whether the user chooses confirm or cancel within the dialog. If both views need access to the same model you could pass it in to them when you instantiate them.

Answer (score 0):

I think .then() always gets called on a $.when. have you tried .done() instead of .then?

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/